# SQL: One to many relationship -- return only desired value

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I have two tables, where the first table is a list of accounts

```
Account
100
200
300
400
500
600
```

The second table is a subset of these accounts that are linked to a various account maps. This table has one-to-many relationship.

```
Linked Account  Account Map
100 BS1
100 IS1
100 PRD
200 NULL
300 IS1
300 PRD
400 BS1
500 NULL
600 BS1
600 IS1
```

I want to find which accounts are mapped to BS1 and which are not.
If the account is mapped to BS1, show ‘BS1’ and if the account is mapped to any other account map or not mapped at all, show it is as ‘Null’.

Here’s the output that I am looking for.

```
Account Account Map
100 BS1
200 NULL
300 NULL
400 BS1
500 NULL
600 BS1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This isn't a free coding service. Please take the [tour], and especially read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A simple left join should work here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Account,
    CASE WHEN la.Account IS NOT NULL THEN 'BS1' END AS label
FROM Account a
LEFT JOIN LinkedAccounts la
    ON a.Account = la.Account AND
       la.Map = 'BS1';
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Hope Can Help you

```
Select * Into #MstAcc From (
    Select '100' [Account] Union All
    Select '200' [Account] Union All
    Select '300' [Account] Union All
    Select '400' [Account] Union All
    Select '500' [Account] Union All
    Select '600' [Account] 
) A


Select * Into #LinkAcc From (
    Select '100' [Account], 'BS1' [Map] Union All
    Select '100' [Account], 'IS1' [Map] Union All
    Select '100' [Account], 'PRD' [Map] Union All
    Select '300' [Account], 'IS1' [Map] Union All
    Select '300' [Account], 'PRD' [Map] Union All
    Select '400' [Account], 'BS1' [Map] Union All
    Select '600' [Account], 'BS1' [Map] Union All
    Select '600' [Account], 'IS1' [Map] 
) A

Select #MstAcc.Account, A.Map From #MstAcc
Left Join (
    Select Account, Min(Map) Map From #LinkAcc
    Where Map = 'BS1'
    Group By Account
) A On A.Account  = #MstAcc.Account
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are variations on Tim's answer, which should have better performance (`SELECT DISTINCT` incurs overhead).  Assuming there are no duplicates in `LinkedAccounts`:

```
SELECT a.Account, la.Account as label
FROM Account a LEFT JOIN
     LinkedAccounts la
     ON la.Account = a.Account AND
        la.Map = 'BS1';
```

If there are, use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.Account,
       (SELECT la.Map
        FROM LinkedAccounts la
        WHERE la.Account = a.Account AND
              la.Map = 'BS1'
        LIMIT 1
       ) as label
FROM Account a;
```